# How to expose custom webform fields to GraphQL?

Tags: webforms

I would like to use https://www.drupal.org/project/captcha with Webforms. For exposing Webforms via GraphQL I use https://github.com/duartegarin/graphql_webform.

As CAPTCHA is not a standard field https://github.com/duartegarin/graphql_webform does not expose it via GraphQL. As I did not find any documentation on how to expose custom webform fields to GraphQL I thought I ask about it here.

Thank you.

Comment: Since your question is specific to a module that is not on drupal.org, I would ask in the module's issue queue instead: https://github.com/duartegarin/graphql_webform/issues

Answer (score 1):

The CAPTCHA module doesn't implement a webform component. It just adds a form element to the forms for which it has been configured to add its CAPTCHA.

If the CAPTCHA module implemented a webform component, then implementing a few classes (starting from a plugin like [`WebformElementPhone`](https://github.com/duartegarin/graphql_webform/blob/master/src/Plugin/GraphQL/Types/WebformElementPhone.php#L19)) would allow to integrate the modules together.

```php
/**
 * A GraphQL type for textfield form item.
 *
 * @GraphQLType(
 *   id = "webform_element_phone",
 *   name = "WebformElementPhone",
 *   interfaces = {"WebformElementTextBase"},
 * )
 */
class WebformElementPhone extends TypePluginBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function applies($object, ResolveContext $context, ResolveInfo $info) {
    return $object['plugin'] instanceof Telephone;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, I wrote a WebformElementCaptcha, returning an instance of Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformElement\Captcha. But I am unable to access any fields of the Captcha. I also tried to create a new interface. But the example WebformElementTextBase is empty, so I do not know how to expose the values.

Comment: Okay, I think I have to write a custom WebformElement. But I do not understand the structure of $value. `json_encode($value)` is a good return value in resolveValues for debugging. (But it looks like the capture itself is not returned, only the title, the description and what type of captcha is used).

Comment: The first step is implementing a webform component for the CAPTCHA, then a `GraphQLType` for that webform component. It's not a simple task and it requires to understand what the purpose of all the classes is.